# Seeing the past

Tags: particle-physics, visible-light, photons

What if I manage to trap the photons reflected by me .
And then saw that photons after some time ? I'm seeing in the past then ?

Comment: Yes. For example, one way to trap the photons is to have them hit a special chemical film, which remembers their color and intensity, then look at the film later. This is called "taking a photo".

Comment: @knzhou . But if they'll hit by the chemical screen then It should be possible that my body's information destroyed , as they are now acquired the information of chemical screen ?

Comment: when one is observing sun  by some means of projecting  its image  say by a pin hole  you are not actually looking at the present moment.
 Instead, you are looking at -what the Sun looked like approx..  8 minutes ago. This is because light has finite speed  and those same light rays from the Sun that are striking your screen  took 8 minutes to reach Earth. In other words,  by the time those rays reached us, we had already advanced 8 minutes into the future. therefore one can see in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Every information received by detecting photons is information about the past. How far in the past depends on the distance from the object that emitted or reflected the photons. So yes, if you look in the mirror or at a photo of yourself, or whenever you look at anything, you are in fact looking into the past.